# Why is Architecture menu tab in VS2015 RC Ultimate missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-map

I would like to use the feature to see dependency(CodeMap?) of a Class/Project, not the TypeDependency at the Solution level (that's way too much more info than I need). To view TypeDependency, Microsoft documentation says

> "Get an overview of your solution: On the Architecture menu, choose
>   Generate Dependency Graph, For Solution."

I did notice it says Solution, but isn't this available at Class/Project level? More importantly, why is my VS missing the Architecture tab entirely? Anyways, I am using VS2015 RC Ultimate (I can tell because there is CodeLens). Is there some additional steps I need to do to make it visible or is there an alternative way to generate CodeMap? [image]

Comment: DO you still have problems now that VS 2015 Enterprise RTM is out?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is missing because you have installed resharper. I am guessing it overrides the VS functions with its own functionalites. Resharper should have a similar codeMap.

If not have you tried if u can use it via 'quick launch'? or install it with NuGet?

Are you sure there is an ultimate version of VS2015RC yet?

Comment: I just tried with QuickLaunch and that didn't help. One reason why I think the VS I am using is Ultimate is because of the CodeLens feature. I think CodeLens is available in Ultimate and above only.

Comment: i like how microsoft creates confusion! there will be no Ultimate or Premium version anymore. It is called Enterprise Edition from now on. visualstudio.com/en-us/vs-2015-product-editions